# How to add custom data in firebase database with email+pass firebase auth in angular

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, angular-services

I'm trying to take additional data from a user registration form and put it into a firebase users database. I am able to get the email+password, however, I am unable to get any other fields working.

I have tried adding more variables to the `this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` however it only works with two.

Here is code from the auth.service.ts (the SignUp function and the functions that are also shown within it):

```
// Sign up with email/password
  SignUp(email, password) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        /* Call the SendVerificaitonMail() function when new user sign 
        up and returns promise */
        this.SendVerificationMail();
        this.SetUserData(result.user);
      }).catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message)
      })
  }

// Send email verfificaiton when new user sign up
  SendVerificationMail() {
    return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
    .then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['verify-email-address']);
    })
  }

SetUserData(user) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
    const userData: User = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photoURL: user.photoURL,
      emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
      department: user.department
    }
    return userRef.set(userData, {
      merge: true
    })
  }
```

Here is data from the registration.component
(TS File first)

```
// This is where the only modification in the TS file is - the rest is the default (CLI made)
constructor(
    public authService: AuthService
  ) { }
```

(HTML File)

```
<div class="displayTable">
  <div class="displayTableCell">

    <div class="authBlock">
      <h3>Sign Up</h3>

      <div class="formGroup">
        <input type="email" class="formControl" placeholder="Email Address" #userEmail required>
      </div>

      <div class="formGroup">
        <input type="password" class="formControl" placeholder="Password" #userPwd required>
      </div>
      <div class="formGroup">
          <input type="text" class="formControl" placeholder="Department" #userDept required>
      </div>
      <div class="formGroup">
        <input type="button" class="btn btnPrimary" value="Sign Up" (click)="authService.SignUp(userEmail.value, userPwd.value, userDept.value)">
      </div>

    <div class="redirectToLogin">
      <span>Already have an account? <span class="redirect" routerLink="/sign-in">Log In</span></span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

The desired result:
Have the department (and any other fields added) added to the database along with the email + password that is already there.

The actual result:
I an error (as shown below) get when trying to submit the department with the `authService.SignUp()` function. (Through the signup form on the website).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOJ5J.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is correct, `department` is `undefined`, thus firebase complains. You are in your template passing the department:

```
authService.SignUp(userEmail.value, userPwd.value, userDept.value)
```

But in your corresponding function, you have not added it as a parameter, so first add it and also pass it to `SetUserData`:

```ts
SignUp(email, password, department) { // add here!
  return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((result) => {
      // ...
      this.SetUserData(result.user, department); // add as parameter also!
    })
    // ...
}
```

In `SetUserData` also add it as parameter, and now you have access to the value!

```ts
SetUserData(user, department) { // added as parameter
  // ...
  const userData: User = {
    uid: user.uid,
    email: user.email,
    displayName: user.displayName,
    photoURL: user.photoURL,
    emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
    department: department // HERE!
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: That's what I already have going on there - I just don't know how to further take fields from the form and set them in the database for the user.

Comment: Oh, didn't look too closely, anyway, updated my answer and it should work now :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll test it shortly however it looks pretty good!

Comment: Alright. I tested it and that works fine however now it is not showing up in my dashboard component when I try to call it like `{{user.department}}` but things like `{{user.uid}}` and `{{user.email}}` don't work. Below is the div the binding is supposed to be taking place:
`<div *ngIf="authService.userData as user"> <h1>Hello: {{(user.displayName) ? user.displayName : 'User'}}</h1><p>User ID: {{user.uid}</p><p>Email: {{user.email}}</p><p>Department: {{user.department}}</p></div>`

Comment: Have you debugged? What does `console.log(result.user)` print?

Comment: You need to do some debugging yourself. Put console logs on all places and see how data looks like. Also, are you seeing values in the db?

Comment: I am seeing the values in the database. I tried placing console.log all over the place with a variety of things (eg. after signup with all of the values entered, during sign in) and (I either don't know where to look or) the department does not show up/get fetched.

Comment: I'm confused... What data is sjowing and what not? First you said that department works, and now you say it doednt? You are fetching both user objects tho, right?

Comment: Department wasn't working to begin with and that's what I was looking to fix. (Both collecting the department from the form but also the string interpolation in the html of the dashboard component). The name, UID, and email are showing just fine and I am not sure how to get the department to show up as it is in the database and it (I think) should be working.

Comment: Are you getting **both** user objects, dince the department is only available in one of the tables.

Comment: Which are the two user objects? In the user object it shows all of the data and when fetching for it *I believe* that it goes to the database (which houses the user with all of the fields (department, email, userName, etc))

Comment: well one of the users is fetched from the auth table `this.afAuth.authState` and the second one, where the department value is in, is fetched from `this.afs.doc(``users/${user.uid}``)` Can't help further when not seeing the code.

Comment: Got ya. I'll look into that.

Comment: Would this code be where I would need to change something to go to the database instead of the authState? 
```this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      }
    })```

Comment: That piece of code get's the data from the auth users table, the `department` value is not present there. You need to query the other table too. From `this.afs.doc(\`users/${user.uid}\`)`

Comment: Do you know how I would go about doing that? I tried looking it up and I am not sure what to do - do I have to get the code from both or just the db?

Comment: Read the tutorial on how to get a document: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md